# How can I fix the websocket limits for `Connection duration for WebSocket API: 2 hours`

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am using API Gateway websocket connection and I have read this limits:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

It says the Connection duration for WebSocket API limits is 2 hours. Does this mean I can't keep the connection connected for more than 2 hours? If yes, what is the workaround for that? Should I have to re-establish the connection every 2 hours in order to keep it connected?

Comment: Not sure if you solved it or not, but you should use a PING PONG schema https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-37
You need to be able to reconnect if you lose the connection. However I am not sure why there is that 2 hours limit on top of the 10 minutes idle, not really clear what does it mean

Comment: I am experiencing this timeout behaviour. The System.Net.WebSockets.Client we are using does seem to be receiving a WebSocketMessageType.Close message so I plan to use that to trigger a reconnect from the client perspective.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: How can i tweak 2 hour configuration limit in AWS?

Comment: This 2 hour limit is likely there so that AWS's infrastructure can drain WebSocket connections off of internal load balancers when they need to make configuration changes or apply software patches. If you consider that API Gateway can manage millions of simultaneous WebSocket connections for you while also keeping them individually addressable for messages sent by the server, you can reason that something had to give, and that something was connection lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by implementing reconnection mechanism from client. Client simply reconnects to the server once the connection is dropped by API gateway after 2 hours. Found this as a recommended solution at multiple places.

Comment: More details links to those solutions pleas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

even if you have client logic to reconnect when AWS kills the connection after 2 hours, that means 12 times/day you risk losing messages while the connection is being re-established.  Doesn't seem like a good solution